# sending ,receiving and unregister of stickyBroadcast in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem with stickyBroadcast that values which are sent through stickyBroadcast are not changed even after app crashed.
Briefly..
i am running a service in background when ever its completed, i send a "true" boolean variable to Activiy through stickyBroadcast. and i remove this stickyBroadcast in TabActivity onPause,
when i close the app this stickyBroadcast was removed correctly.and when i reopen app the fresh value sending through stickyBroadcat. up to this my code is working fine

when app being crashed by any reason the value in this stickyBroadcast was not removed.
if i again reopen the app old value was being sent by stickyBroadcast

could any one help me how to handle the stickyBroadcast when app being crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think you have to put your code in `Try and Catch` Block .

so when app will crash or get any exception that will handle . Now Write your code for

`Distroy  stickyBroadcast` in catch so it will handle.

Now When you launch next Time after crash app it will always fresh data.

Hope it's Work .